# Remove elements containing specific char from array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is an extract from my array:

```
Array
(
    [8] => Array
        (
            [item] => (pen)
            [sku] => 3
        )
    [11] => Array
        (
            [item] => cup
            [sku] => 34
        )
    [12] => Array
        (
            [item] => (bottle)
            [sku] => 23
        )
)
```

I have to unset all elements where "item" contains a bracket, so in the example I only have to get [8] back.

I've already tried this one:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $ll) {
    if (strpos($ll,'(') !== false) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

But this clears the whole array so I don't get results.

What's the right solution?

Comment: You do mean [11] not [8] right?  [8] and [12] both have parentheses that I assume you are calling a "bracket".

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm sorry, yes. 8 & 12 have to be removed.

Comment: @chris85 the array is built from a JSON response from my api.

Comment: Is `$arr` the original array? If so, you should be checking `$ll['item']`, not `$ll`.

Comment: You should be getting this error: "strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given".  From there, you should be able to figure out what the problem is.  If you're not getting that error, turn your error reporting on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is multidimensional, you need to check `item`:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $ll) {
    if (strpos($ll['item'], '(') !== false) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```

Alternately, filter by trimming `()` and comparing with the original, especially if you want to check for `(` OR `)` or just `)`:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($v) { return trim($v['item'], '()') == $v['item']; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here using `array_filter` and a custom callback, and a Regx

```
$b = array_filter( $array , function( $a ){
   return !preg_match('/^\([^)]+\)$/', $a['item']);
} );
```

You can test it here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/613514eaaa6f669d5fdc67706b60c0b90ea456b0

Basically returning the negative of the Regx, which matches anything that starts and ends with a `(...)`, removes those items from the array.  ( return false for array_filter )

-note- Unsetting things inside a foreach loop is a bad idea.  Sometimes this can create some weird behavior because PHP creates a temporary cached array of the original for use with the loop.  Typically problems happen when using pass by reference in the foreach but I wouldn't trust it.

I've seen some really weird stuff happen when making changes to the array structure ... lol.

Comment: or take the preg_grep function directly: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Answer (score -2):

You are not checking `item` element. Try this:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $ll) {
    if (strpos($ll['item'], '(') !== false) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
}
```